# How to extract SQL Server image column data into readable format and store into another column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server database in which there are around 5 lac records in a table called `message_mst`, here is the table structure

Table name : `message_mst`

Columns:

```
message_id       int
message_body     image
```

I am not the person who built this database but whoever built this used `image` column to store all the message text which is simply plain text. But if we select the records, `message_body` prints all the text in HEX format. I want to convert it into readable format and then store into new field called `message_body_readable`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it  converting the field first to `varbinary` and than to `varchar`.

```
declare @t table (i image) 

insert into @t values('some text')

select i, CAST(cast(i as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))
from @t
```

Comment: No it did not help, returned blank records :(

Comment: Can you show us the code that inserts data into the field. Are there any datatype conversions? Also, datatype can be converted by client application.

Comment: @aslamdoctor I meant not the data that stored in the field but program code that inserts the data into the field.

Comment: Its storing using stored procedure and there is no conversion or encryption getting done before storing this data. Its going straight away from textarea to database.

Comment: I mean the procedure is called straight away after getting the Textarea values and there is no conversion or encryption done on this text under stored procedure. Its just insert query in there.

Comment: @aslamdoctor Than, unfortunately, I can't say what can be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this once..?

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), message_body, 0) FROM  message_mst
```